# Misleading 404 error with Tastypie API

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'am using the lasted version of Tastypie for a simple API resource.

On a post Tastypie gave me a 404 file not found reply. Looking at my logs the error actually turned out to be me not posting the User FK correctly. However, I found the 404 error very misleading.

Is this a normal response to an error in TastyPie? If not I'm I doing something wrong?